# dynamic library in application bundle Mac os X

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using dynamic libraries in my application and now i need to distribute this application to users. I want to put all the dynamic libraries in bundle instead of installing the dynamic libraries in lib,usr/lib .. etc , so that it would be clean deployment and easy to maintain. 
Problem is  when i put dyanamic libraries in Xcode application as a framework its not working .Please help me how can i do this ? 
I want to make sure my application uses dynamic libraries from bundle not from system libs . Please advice

Answer (score 7):

Dunno if there's a way to specify that inside Xcode or not, but for our app we use a build script that includes some code like the following.  The code uses Apple's install_name_tool utility to modify the application so that instead of pointing to /usr/lib/libsndfile.so, it points to a libsndfile.so path that is in the application's package instead.

Note this is just a cut-down script excerpt to give you an idea; it will probably require some tweaking before it works for you (and of course you'll need to modify it to operate on other libraries besides libsndfile if that is what you want):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

BINARY="MyAppFolder/MyAppName"
FRAMEW_FOLDER="MyAppFolder/MyAppName/Contents/Frameworks/"

function DoInstallNameTool {
    xLIB="$1"
    xLIB_NAME="$2"
    xBINARY="$3"
    echo install_name_tool -change \"${xLIB}\" \"@executable_path/../Frameworks/${xLIB_NAME}\" \"${xBINARY}\"
    install_name_tool -change ${xLIB} "@executable_path/../Frameworks/${xLIB_NAME}" "${xBINARY}"
}

for LIB in $(otool -L "${BINARY}"|grep libsndfile|cut -d '(' -f -1)
do
    echo "Handling Lib: $LIB"
    LIB_NAME=$(basename "$LIB")
    echo "    Adding ${LIB_NAME}"
    cp -Rf "${LIBSNDFILE_DIR}/src/.libs/${LIB_NAME}" "${FRAMEW_FOLDER}"

    DoInstallNameTool "$LIB" "$LIB_NAME" "$BINARY"
done
```

After the script runs, you can do a

```
otool -L ./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

to print out all the shared libraries the app depends on, to verify that the script worked (or if it didn't work, to see what /usr/lib/* libraries the app is still dynamically linked to)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the reply .. let me check with it .. Thanks one more time